# Storing Special Character in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, jdbc

I am using mysql query browser to store the following names in the Person table which contains fields of personNumber and personName. I have the character set of personName at utf-8 and if i insert the name via query browse the query is running correctly but when i try that via JDBC or JPA, the name's special characters become the '?'. What is the problem here?...

The names are 
1.Năstase 
2.Hrustanović
3.Ogris-Martič and some similar names.

Comment: Add the code which you're currently trying.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set your connection string correctly?

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/administer?characterEncoding=utf8
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MY_DB?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8
```